# Xcode Interface Builder set highlighted image for button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface

I'm making an cocoa application from Mac OS X, not for iphone.

I am able to set the background image of a button and uncheck bordered in the attribute inspector. However, I do not know how I set the image for when you click on it (highlighted/on click, whatever you want to call it). I want to do this because

I have found guides on google to do this with UIbutton but this isn't helpful since I'm making this for Mac.

I am using [InAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) and the button is in the Title bar. When I click on the button with the custom image, the background goes white: [image: custom background with white button]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are getting white background when button is clicked because You're using incorrect type. You need to change button's type to ***Momentary Change***. You can change it in *Attributes inspector*:

[image: how to do it]

Or change programatically:

```
[buttonOutlet setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
```

And for **highlighting**: just add another image as **alternate** image in *Attributes Inspector* and it will be shown when button pressed.